# Is whitelisting ajax server-side page safe?

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, security, csrf

If I reject (with htaccess file) any request that does not come from a certain page of my website, can I be sure that noone can really access it in malicious ways?

```
# whitelist POST requests
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ajax/file.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !127.0.0.1 
    RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: if javascript on client's computer has access to the page - user will have access to

Comment: AJAX requests will not come from 127.0.0.1, unless you happen to be browsing your local webserver.

Comment: @rjdown You are both totally right, so the only way to do multiple request from the same page with ajax is using multiple tokens?

Comment: I recommend using the session data to validate the request

Comment: @rjdown good solution, but vulnerable CSRF Attacks

Comment: Well, I said validate, not blindly use

Comment: @rjdown sorry, I missunderstood